# Deny property editing from anywhere inside class but inside function

Tags: swift

Is there any way to restrict property being set inside class from anywhere but function? Here is code to illustrate the problem:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
var property: Int?

func setProperty(_ property: Int?, animated: Bool,
                 withColor color: UIColor,
                 andSomethingElse something: Any) {
    // only allow property to be set here
    self.property = property

    // ...
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // What I'd like to achieve is deny following...
    property = 42

    // ...and somehow force to set value exclusively via function
    setProperty(42,
                animated: true,
                withColor: .green,
                andSomethingElse: LongCat())
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any language mechanic that allows you to do that. You could use `private` for other classes not to use that.

If you care that much you can make a wrapper class for that property, but I believe this is more hassle than it is worth.

Usually this is a good place to make the property named like `_property` to signal that it is private or add a comment above.